# Can't create a Facebook ad for other pages than our own

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using the Facebook Marketing API to publish link ads to Facebook. This includes creating a campaign, an ad set and an ad creative, using a specific advertising (ad) account, an app (developer level) and an access token. This all works well when I publish to pages managed by our organization (our Business Manager). The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to publish ads for other pages than our own, or have other pages as the "sender" of the ad.

Our process looks like this:

1. User logs on to our site and goes to the Facebook advertisement section.
2. The user is prompted to log in / connect to Facebook and authorize our app. The current permissions that we ask for are public_profile and publish_pages (but I've tried adding more, e.g. ads_management without success).
3. The user then creates the ad by choosing an image, text, budget, duration, etc.
4. Success (hopefully).

What we have:

1. A Facebook Ad Account (managed by Facebook Business Manager).
2. A Facebook app (in developer mode) that is "connected" (has the ad ID in Authorized Ad Account IDs) to the above ad account.
3. An Admin System User access token generated in Business Manager. This user has access to our own pages and apps. If I debug this token I can see that is is indeed referencing the correct Facebook app. All API calls from the server (e.g. create ad) are made with this access token.

The call I'm trying to make (that fails for a page not owned by us) is basically a HTTP POST to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_xxxxxx/adcreatives like such:

```
{
  "accessToken": "abc123",
  "name": "Test",
  "objectStorySpec": {
    "linkData": {
      "link": "http://www.a-link.com",
      "name": "Test",
      "description": "Testing",
      "message": "Testing",
      "picture": "http://www.a-link-to-a-picture.com/image.jpg"
    },
    "pageId": "12345678554"
  }
}
```

The error message that I get back from Facebook is: "Application does not have permission for this action"

Comment: What is your marketing API access level? Pretty sure you need at least Basic, if you want to be able to perform operations for other accounts

Comment: Unfortunately it's still Development, but that's a really feasible reason. I'll see about getting it upgraded, thanks a bunch for the (quick) reply!

Comment: Did you ever get passed this problem? @MarcusW

Comment: Yes I think so, but I can't really remember how at the moment. It might have been something along the lines of your ad account has to be set as a manager of the page that you are trying to post the ad on behalf of. Or something like that...